# How do I display my R shiny code in the R shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to include my code in my R Shiny app, as shown below, however, I am not able to find any way to do it! Here is my desired output, as you can see there is a app.R file that displays all of the code within an app:
[my desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyHZo.png)

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using the [showcase mode](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html).

Invoke `runApp` directly with `display.mode="showcase"`:

```R
shiny::runApp(display.mode="showcase")
```